# Example for a non-semisimple algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Why is the $\mathbb{C}[X]/\langle X^2\rangle$-module $\mathbb{C^2}$ with $X$ acting as $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ not a direct sum of simple modules?

As far as I understand, the action is $[X]\cdot(x,y)=(y,0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple modules over a commutative ring $R$ are of the form $R/\mathfrak{m}$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. The only maximal ideal of $\Bbb C[X]/(X^2)$ is $(X)/(X^2)$, so the only simple module is $(\Bbb C[X]/(X^2))/((X)/(X^2)) \cong \Bbb C$ with $X$ acting trivially. Thus $X$ acts trivially on any direct sum of simple modules.

Comment: Why does $X$ act trivially and why is that a problem?

Comment: @VML I showed that $X$ acts trivially on any simple module, thus it also acts trivially on any direct sum of simple modules. $X$ doesn't act trivially in the module of your question.

Comment: And this can't be since $X$ acts non-trivially on the given module, got it. But why does $X$ acts trivially on your module which is isomorphic to the complex numbers?

Comment: @VML we're modding out the ideal generated by $X$, thus $X=0$ in the quotient. (Alternatively, what are the nilpotent $\Bbb C$-linear endomorphisms of $\Bbb C$?)